# Does Docker build a base image everytime a "child" container is run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am new to `docker` and the world of `containers`..Am using `Microsoft servercore` as my `base image`, and need an application installed on it, which I copy and install on the `image`, and copy some other files besides. I then build this image and use it as a `base image` for another container which works on these files.

However, it takes a long time for the second `container` to start doing its job, which left me wondering if Docker containers build their base images from scratch everytime they are run.

If this is the case, then is it possible for me to build a base image which comes installed with everything I need, so all the steps in the base image build (copying files, installing etc.) are not carried out everytime it is consumed by a "child" container?

If it is not the case, is there a reason why the child container should start that late? 
Some way to check which step is being executed by a container, perhaps?

**UPDATE** - I checked in a crude way, by removing one of the files which get copied into the base image, and by checking if it would create issues, but it didn't, so quite likely the base image container does not get built everytime it is consumed by a child container, but the time taken between Docker Run and the execution of a simple batch as the first step is quite high...

**UPDATE 2** - For more clarity...

**DockerFile 1** (builds as testdocker)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore  
ADD 7z1900-x64.exe /7z1900-x64.exe  
RUN powershell.exe -Command Start-Process .\7z1900-x64.exe -ArgumentList '/S /D=c:/' -Wait
```

**Dockerfile 2**

```
FROM testdocker
COPY testbat.bat /testbat.bat
CMD testbat.bat && cmd
```

**Batch file executed in second container**

```
@ECHO ON
dir
pause
```

Comment: Docker won't create another image, but the startup time may be caused by the script launched on startup which takes a lot of resources or is doing a kind of "setup" of the container

Comment: By script, do you mean to say the script which I've written and am using, or some `docker` script? I reduced, just for checking, to a single ADD command of a few kb file, and running DIR, but a FROM from this image also takes considerable period, almost 40-50 seconds before I see an output. So I wonder if there's something else going on while setting up the container, as you mentioned, which is Docker controlled. Is there a log or a way to output what the `docker run` command is doing in the background before executing the batch file?

Comment: When you're using FROM you mean you're building the image (with `docker build`) ? `docker run` will roughly create and start a container. From this point, it's most likely what takes time is the ENTRYPOINT command defined on the image. If `docker run` takes a long time before executing the script, try with `docker create` then `docker start` and see which takes most time: if it's `create`, there is something strange happening when container is created (independent from your script), however if `start` takes a long time issue may be with your script - but all this subject is another question :)

Comment: Yes, I build an image first, containing the relevant files and installations. This is then used as a base image for another container using FROM. So let's say I build image1 (derived from servercore) first, in which I add a file and script, install an application. Thereafter I have a second container with Dokcerfile saying FROM image1 and then CMD with the script file in the base image. Script has dir as first instruction, and it takes a long time to execute, meaning something has been going on before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base image is readonly for docker, so docker will not build base image everytime they run.

But base image may has [`ONBUILD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#onbuild)  instruction, from offical document its behavior is:

> As part of processing the FROM instruction, the downstream builder looks for ONBUILD triggers, and executes them in the same order they were registered. If all triggers succeed, the FROM instruction completes and the build continues as usual.